# Update Javascript library JQuery Migrate from version 1.x to latest stable version 3.4.0

Tags: jquery-migrate

I am currently working on a code which has Javascript library Jquery Migrate which  currently uses version 1.4.1. Can someone guide me how can I update the Jquery Migrate library to version 3.4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this `npm i jquery-migrate@3.4.0`. You can replace the 3.4.0 with every version you'd liked.